# Detail page in Magento2 render empty

Tags: layout, magento2

I have created my own new theme in Magento 2 clone from blank theme of Magento2.

When I open up product view page,  It's showing blank page (Body totally blank).

I have re-checked all my settings through my new theme like (syntax error, html and layout files) but its seems good.

How to fix this this issue? Anyone getting same this problem ?

Comment: You can see layout files in my github
https://github.com/mrtuvn/ves.market.v2
Cache , pub/static already cleaned

Comment: not working. but thank you for response
Any suggestions to fix this issue

Comment: After long R & D , I found that your theme structure is not valid. I tried to call `grunt exec:market`, Theme Clean up is working. but exception is found while creating to symlink of `.less` files. Please follow the `luma` theme structure and remove unwanted .less from your theme.

Comment: Please follow the instruction for Theme Creation in Magento 2 at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html